# Можно ли упростить данный код в python?

Tags: python

Можно ли упростить данный код? А то код получается длинный и мне кажется что есть способ это все организовать компактнее.

```
tournament_header = driver.find_element("css selector", "span.tournamentHeader__country").text
if "АНГЛИЯ: ПРЕМЬЕР-ЛИГА" in tournament_header:
  tournament.append("английской Премьер-лиги")
elif "АНГЛИЯ: ЧЕМПИОНШИП" in tournament_header:
    tournament.append("английского Чемпионшипа")
elif "ИСПАНИЯ: ПРИМЕРА" in tournament_header:
    tournament.append("испанской Примеры")
elif "ИСПАНИЯ: СЕГУНДА" in tournament_header:
    tournament.append("испанской Сегунды")
...
```

Comment: Сделайте словарь ключ:значение и берите из него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант основанный на словаре вполне рабочий, но предложу еще один вариант,
он так же основан на словаре, причем в обоих смыслах - лингвистическом и программном.

В чем основная польза такого подхода, он позволяет сократить рутину ввода названий основываясь на грамматике языка. Таким образом происходит тоже сокращение кода (если стран очень много)

Конечно, `грамматика` - тут чисто условное обозначение и может быть для конкретно этого случая такой подход слишком затратный, но я уверен что он имеет право на жизнь, в более сложных случаях, когда лень вводить все страны) На мой взгляд проще работать с окончаниями Амер`ика`, Афр`ика` -> иканской (убили двух зайцев). Конечно, могут быть исключения (не смог найти), но думаю их не настолько много, чтобы не обработать их отдельно если необходимо.

```
import re

tournament_header = '''ИСПАНИЯ: СЕГУНДА АНГЛИЯ: ПРЕМЬЕР-ЛИГА 
АНГЛИЯ: ЧЕМПИОНШИП ИСПАНИЯ: ПРИМЕРА'''

tournament = [] 

ends = {
  'F' : {'лия': 'ийской',  'ния': 'ской' }, # женский род
  'M' : {'лия': 'ийского',  'ния': 'ского' } # мужской род
}

types = {
  'ПРЕМЬЕР-ЛИГ': ['И', ends['F']],
  'ЧЕМПИОНШИП': ['A', ends['M']],
  'ПРИМЕР': ['Ы', ends['F']],
  'СЕГУНД': ['Ы', ends['F']]
}

def first_big(x): return x[0].upper() + x[1:].lower()
def make_reg(pattern): return re.compile( f'([А-Я]*): ({pattern})') 
def get_type(t, end): return first_big(t + end)
def get_country(c, ends): return c.lower()[0:-2] + ends[c.lower()[-3:]]

COUNTRY = 1
TYPE = 2
TYPE_END = 0
COUNTRY_ENDS = 1

for t in types:
  res = make_reg(t).search(tournament_header)
  if (res): 
    print(get_country(res.group(COUNTRY),types[t][COUNTRY_ENDS]) + ' '
      + get_type(res.group(TYPE), types[t][TYPE_END] ))
```

Вывод

```
английской Премьер-лиги
английского Чемпионшипa
испанской Примеры
испанской Сегунды
```

Comment: большое человеческое спасибо. Как раз нужно было склонять множество клубов, и вот вашим методом я разбираюсь с клубами, которых невероятно много, а с лигами я взял другой код выше.

Comment: рад что удалось помочь, если будут вопросы, уточняйте

Answer (score 3):

```
tournament_header = "ИСПАНИЯ: ПРИМЕРА - ТУР 9"
tournament_strings = ["АНГЛИЯ: ПРЕМЬЕР-ЛИГА", "АНГЛИЯ: ЧЕМПИОНШИП", "ИСПАНИЯ: ПРИМЕРА", "ИСПАНИЯ: СЕГУНДА"]
tournaments = ["английской Премьер-лиги", "английского Чемпионшипа", "испанской Примеры", "испанской Сегунды"]
tournament = []
for x, z in zip(tournament_strings, tournaments):
    if x in tournament_header:
        tournament.append(z)

print(tournament)

#['испанской Примеры']
```